# Are there any personal developer push notification APIs?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push

I'd like to be able to run a curl command on my local machine or on my server, and have a push notification be sent to my cell phone. I can already get the same effect with a text messaging service, but I was wondering what push notification services are available.

Basically I want an alert on my phone when events happen, for my own personal use, and was wondering what's the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't personally used it, but I've read and heard a lot about [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) with which you may be able to do this.